# Multiple Radio Groups with Radio Buttons on check true/false method

Tags: android, methods, radio-button, radio-group

I'm making a quiz app, LinearLayout (vert) with ScrollView and many layouts (h-200dp, w-match parent) inside. Each of this layouts contains a picture on the left side , on the right side there is a RadioGroup with 3 RadioButtons with answers, and one ImageView field below the RadioGroup. (example: picture of a city with 3 offered answers and only one is correct)

I'm trying to write a method that will get ID of those RadioButtons, and on click recognize if true or false. Actually I was thinking about 2 methods, one for true, and one for false answer.

I also need to post an image in the little field below, depending on the answer, is it true (first image) or false (second image). That means my method would have to get ID of that ImageView field for each question (inner layout), and post one of two images.

Anybody with idea what is the best way to handle this situation? Since this is my first app that I'd really like to publish, it would mean a lot to me to get help from someone more experienced. 
Thanks in advance :)

Here's some of code done.
My way requires too much hard coding, imagine if I want to have 40 questions in  a row. So I'm trying to make it simpler

Layout(only one layout posted to shorten the cod displayed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/rain">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:weightSum="1">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/imageView007"
                            android:src="@mipmap/opasnost_na_putu"
                            android:layout_weight="0.68" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp">

                        <RadioGroup
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:id="@+id/rg_opasnost_na_putu">

                            <RadioButton
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Opasnost na putu"
                                android:id="@+id/radioButton" />

                            <RadioButton
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Opasna krivina"
                                android:id="@+id/radioButton2" />

                            <RadioButton
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Suzenje puta"
                                android:id="@+id/radioButton3" />
                        </RadioGroup>

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:id="@+id/imageView37"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
                     ...
                     ...
                     ...
                    </LinearLayout>
               </ScrollView>
          </LinearLayout>
```

Code(also only one Radio Group showed in code to shorten it):

```
public class Znaci_IN_Activity extends Activity {
// Points won
public int osvojeniPoeni = 0;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.znaci_in_layout);
// My Radio Group 
 RadioGroup rgDvostrukaKrivinaD = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg_dvostruka_krivina_d);

// ImageView field for posting image if correct/incorrect answer
ImageView iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView007);

rgDvostrukaKrivinaD.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch (checkedId){
                    case R.id.radioButton4:
                        osvojeniPoeni-=1;
                        iv2.setImageResource(R.mipmap.incorrect);
                        break;
                    case R.id.radioButton5:
                        osvojeniPoeni+=2;
                        iv2.setImageResource(R.mipmap.correct);
                        break;
                    case R.id.radioButton6:
                        osvojeniPoeni-=1;
                        iv2.setImageResource(R.mipmap.incorrect);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

//Button with a TextView area to show points won on the end of the quiz
        Button osv_poeni = (Button) findViewById(R.id.osv_poeni);
        final TextView rez = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rez);
        rez.setText(Integer.toString(osvojeniPoeni));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nikolas, can you provide us with some code that you've tried? Your question should be about an issue you're running into, not just how to implement something without any work being put forth by you.

Comment: Since my code is too long, I provided just just a single layout needed for one question in quiz, and a single RadioGroup in class code